# Arc menu like Pinterest (longpress and drag & drop) on flutter

Tags: flutter, menu, drag, long-press

I want to implement Arc Menu like Pinterest.

on iOS:

https://iosexample.com/a-beautiful-and-minimalist-arc-menu-like-the-pinterest-one-written-in-swift/
https://github.com/GnosisHub/GHContextMenu

Is there any similar package/solution on Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

try these,

[flutter_arc_speed_dial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_arc_speed_dial)

[awesome_speed_dial](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_speed_dial)

Comment: I tried, but the behavior is different from what I need. I need long-press enable menu than "drag" for the selection. These packages are long-press enable menu, then "click" for selection.

Answer (score 0):

I was also in need of this feature, so I developed a Flutter package for it called pie_menu. It's available [here on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/pie_menu).

Please share your thoughts if you give it a try!